# How to implement help button

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

The Apple [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/buttons/help-buttons/) documentation reads

> Use the system-provided help button to display help documentation

[image]

What is the system-provided help button in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [NSBezelStyleHelpButton](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsbezelstyle/nsbezelstylehelpbutton?language=objc).

Something like this:

`buttonVar.bezelStyle = NSBezelStyle.SmallSquareBezelStyle`

Also see the helpful [guide to NSButton styles](https://mackuba.eu/2014/10/06/a-guide-to-nsbutton-styles/)